# Former Employer is Asking me to Reimburse them for Cobra I never asked for

Tags: united-states, healthcare, cobra

When I left my former employer, I purchased Health care through the exchange rather than go with Cobra. Apparently, they never canceled my health coverage and are now coming to me for back payment. Can they require I pay them?

Comment: Ask them for your registration record.

Comment: This is really going to depend on exactly which pieces of paper were signed when. Gather as many of those as you can, then consider asking a lawyer. If you'd previously been in a plan which defaulted to annual renewal, and you didn't explicitly cancel it, I think you may have a problem -- but I Am Not A Lawyer, and free legal advice is generally not worth what you paid for it.

Comment: I believe COBRA coverage must be actively requested but it's quite possible you did that without realizing it.  Generally, however, CORBA premiums are paid monthly and, if not paid, the coverage will be terminated.  Many people wait the maximum 60 days and then elect coverage, which gives them another 30 days, and then simply don't pay and the plan terminates.  If they have a claim, they then pay the premium, provided it makes sense, and the plan pays.  So this gives them 90 days of coverage at potentially zero expense.

Comment: This question does fit this site, but it borders on a legal question. Might consider asking on https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I second what @jwh20 said, the last time I did COBRA ~10 years ago, they sent me a bill and I paid it. When my new employer's benefits started, I called to cancel. The rep said just don't pay the next bill and it would automatically cancel. You should verify that this isn't the situation.